# How to handle unauthorized requests(status with 401 or 403) with new httpClient in angular

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

i have guard to my home page like below. `checkTokenValidation` is a method i check validation of token from server. when server response false , my code seems to stop and all things inside `map` does not work anymore.

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {

    return this.authService.checkTokenValidation().pipe(
      map((data) => {
          if (data['ok']) {
            this.router.navigate(['/overview']);
            return false;
          } else {
            return true;
          }
        },
        (error: string) => {
          console.log(error);
        })
    );
  }
```

here is my `checkTokenValidation` code:

```
 checkTokenValidation() {
 const token = this.getToken();
    return this.httpClient.get('http://185.69.54.21/back_end/web/site/check-token', {
      headers: new HttpHeaders().append('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`)
    });
  }
```

Comment: use subscribe instead of pipe and map, httclient returns an observable so, subscribe it to handle response or error

Comment: i can not use subscribe because canActivate don't return subscription value.

Comment: checkTokenValidation method is returning response from get method of httpclient that returns an observable, so you can subscribe to that

Answer (score 0):

### Issues

Suspected issues are -

1. Navigating through the Guard. So better remove from there.
2. Condition is wrong I guess. If data is ok then it should return true else false;
3. In case of error return false;

### Modified code

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {

    return this.authService.checkTokenValidation().pipe(
      map((data) => {
          if (data['ok']) {
            //this.router.navigate(['/overview']); //<-- remove this.
            return true; //<- return true if response is ok
          } else {
            return false;  //<- return false if response is not ok
          }
        },
        (error: string) => {
          console.log(error);
          return false;   //<- return false in case of error
        })
    );
  }
```